# How to grant XA_RECOVER_ADMIN to a new user by root in mysql database

Tags: sql-grant, mysql-8.0

mysql version

```
select @@version;
8.0.18
```

create user

```
create user 'user1'@'%' identified by 'user1_pwd';
```

create database

```
drop database if exists test_db;
create database test_db
character set utf8mb4
collate utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

grant privilege

```
grant XA_RECOVER_ADMIN on test_db.* to 'user1'@'%';
```

error msg

```
[HY000][3619] Illegal privilege level specified for XA_RECOVER_ADMIN
```

what can i do ? can i use a new user to grant XA_RECOVER_ADMIN instead of root?

Answer (score 0):

XA_RECOVER_ADMIN is a global privilege (admins usually operate globally), meaning it cannot be granted on a particular database.

Instead of

```
grant XA_RECOVER_ADMIN on test_db.* to 'user1'@'%';
```

you have to use

```
grant XA_RECOVER_ADMIN on *.* to 'user1'@'%';
```